# Inicializar variável em um "for"

Tags: c#, .net, variáveis, for, declaração-de-variável

Me lembro que na linguagem C eu não precisava inicializar a variável (no caso `i`) com um valor, tentei fazer o mesmo no C# e recebi um erro de compilação.

Em C# eu sou obrigado a definir o valor da variável no início do for? Assim:

```
int i = 1;
for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
```

Não posso simplesmente fazer igual como no C?

```
int i = 1;
for (i; i <= 10; i++)
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Há várias confusões aí.

Em C você não é obrigado a inicializar a variável com um valor, mas isso sempre é um erro para usar em um `for` porque fica imprevisível de onde ele vai começar. Pode até dar certo em várias situações, mas não é correto e haverá situações que não obterá o resultado esperado. Em C# realmente não permite fazer isso porque é quase 100% certo que está errado (no `for` é sempre, mas ele nem diferencia isso).

Esse segundo código não faz o menor sentido em C ou C#, mesmo que uma delas aceite, pra que usar um `i` ali se ele não tem função alguma?  Em um faz o mesmo que fez antes e no outro faz nada.

O primeiro código fica bem melhor em quase todas situações assim:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
```

Então por que fazer diferente? Tem algum motivo? Até existe motivo, mas não parece ser o seu caso. Isto vale para C ou C#, só que em C é comum algumas pessoas estarem presas ao jeito de fazer de 30 anos atrás, não faz mais sentido declarar a variável antes de usá-la.

Se realmente for o caso de fazer a declaração antes, então deveria fazer (em C ou C#):

```
int i = 1;
for (; i <= 10; i++)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/VarDeclarationFor.cs).

Isso só faz sentido se o `i` for usado depois do `for`, **e** se ele é manipulado internamente no `for` ou se é possível sair do `for` antes de completar a contagem (executar todos passos programados), caso contrário não faça assim. mantenha a variável no escopo do `for`.

Pela pergunta não está muito claro que deseja fazer em C# e como faz em C, mas parece ser um erro.

Mas respondendo sua pergunta: não é obrigado inicializar um valor no `for`, só precisa fazer certo, e não pode fazer algo quase aleatório e esperar que funcione.

- Ou declara e inicializa a variável no `for`,
- ou declara e inicializa antes do `for`,
- ou declara a variável antes do `for`e inicializa nele.

O que não pode é tentar usar uma variável sem inicializar.

Inclusive a pergunta dá a entender que o erro é por causa do `for`, mas mesmo o erro não sendo apresentado na pergunta eu posso afirmar que ele tem a ver com o uso da variável e nada a ver com o `for`, qual o sentido de usar uma variável sem fazer nada com ela? Mesmo fora do `for` daria o mesmo erro (por acaso aí está no `for` e deu erro nele, mas só coincidência). É uma pena que C não dá erro.

Considere que não deve fazer isto em C também, só porque dá para fazer não quer dizer que deveria, tem que saber bem porque está fazendo isso para dar certo, caso contrário no máximo funcionará por coincidência. E se o segundo código é o que faz em C, isso não faz o menor sentido.

Comment: Só consegui te responder respondendo à minha própria pergunta, dá uma olhadinha no meu outro comentário, por favor.

Comment: A questão aí é que eu respondi o que você perguntou. Aqui não é um fórum que a gente vai discutindo o assunto em interações, é um site de Q&A, você faz uma pergunta e recebe uma resposta, por isso precisa pensar bem na pergunta que vai fazer pra obter a resposta que deseja. Se tem o utras dúvidas, então deve fazer outras perguntas, não dar uma resposta como se fosse uma pergunta.

Comment: Entendi. É a primeira pergunta que faço aqui no site mesmo, ainda não sei como funciona direito. Consegui resolver o problema usando 2 laços for da forma como você disse for (; i <= 10; i++) Perdão pela pergunta mal elaborada, escrevi o post com pressa e acabei não sendo muito claro. Vlw pela ajuda. Vou apagar o "tópico".

Answer (score -1):

O inicializador do loop **for** é executado apenas uma vez, antes de entrar no loop e pode conter os seguintes critérios:

- A declaração e inicialização de uma variável local, acessível somente dentro do loop

`for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)`

- Instruções de atribuição, incremento, decremento ou invocação de método.

```
int i=0;
for(i=0; i < 5; i++)
for(i++; i < 5; i++)
`for(--i; i < 5; i++)
for(i = getRandomInt(); i < 5; i++)
```